# In app purchase - product list empty - works in sandbox not after publishing

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I tested the in app purchase feature before publishing using sandbox feature and everything worked fine. Today, my app was "ready for sale" and the in app purchase is "approved"

But, for testing reason I tried the app store version and found that in-app purchase products are not lists. The main app is free version and the in-app purchase product is charged. But, when i try from XCode through sandbox it works fine.

1.I tried in a device which is not jail broken
2. The contract, tax and banking is filled and I can see it in "Contracts in effect"
3. "Cleared for sale" is ticked.

Do I need to wait for more hours now and try again? This is my first iOS app, so not sure on how things work in the apple space.

Comment: Now it started working. I had dropped a mail to iTunesConnect. Not sure whether it is cos of that or just out of blue it worked. Anyways.. i can see the purchase popup!

Answer (score 0):

Normally after approving in App purchase from iTunes store. it takes some time to reflect on your app store Application version.